# difference between scaling/normalizing data at a specific step

Tags: machine-learning, preprocessing, normalization, feature-scaling

I am using the ***MinMaxScaler*** normalization method, however I have seen various ways that this can be done, I want to know if there is any actual difference between the following:

**1.** Standardizing/Normalizing the data **before** splitting the data into train and test

**Code 1**

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler() #Normalization
#Transform X and Y values with scaler
x = scaler.fit_transform(x)
y = y.reshape(-1,1)
y = scaler.fit_transform(y)

# Split Data in train and validation
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25)
```

**2.** Standardizing/Normalizing the data **after** splitting the data into train and test and then scaling on train and test

```
# Split Data in train and validation
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25)
  
# created scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler() #Normalization

# transform training dataset
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
# transform test dataset
x_valid = scaler.fit_transform(x_valid)
```

**3.** Standardizing/Normalizing the data **after** splitting the data into train and test. **Then fitting** on the training set and then scaling on both train and test

```
# Split Data in train and validation
x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.25)
  
# created scaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler() #Normalization
# fit scaler on training data
scaler = MinMaxScaler().fit(x_train)

# transform training dataset
x_train = scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
# transform test dataset
x_valid = scaler.fit_transform(x_valid)
```

Comment: In the third one, you are using fit_transform to scale the  x_train and x_valid but it actually fits on your data again and scale rather than only scaling. If you just want to scale using previously fitted information use transform().

Comment: @RAVITEJAM thanks, will make a note out of this :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case I -**

With a single scaling step, you might leak the test info into the train. In this approach you have a common min/max otherwise it would have been two pairs
See, the plot for one of the Features of Iris dataset

*Also, we don't scale the target. But I see this in your code.*

 [image]

**Case II -**

 This is fine but you should also consider the online cases, where you will not have a test set to scale the new test data.

**Case III -**

 This is a better and an agnostic approach.

Your code implementation incorrect as suggested in the comment

Comment: Thank you so much for this profound answer, I really appreciate it and it also clarifies better what I am looking for. Thanks once again :D